# Am I correct when i refuse to give 1 line answers?

Tags: discussion

lately i commented on 2 questions where the answer was really simple.

[This one](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41039/how-can-i-use-one-sound-to-filter-another-sound) and [This one](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41055/low-distorted-signals-from-headworn-microphone)

Both the OPs asked me to form my comment as an answer and i think the right thing is to refuse , cause it's something like "you are looking for a vocoder" or "It's the cable".

I think that there's no purpose for an answer like that nor will i get myself in the trouble of describing the reason a cable does this just to get the 10 points...

Also i feel that there's not posterity value on answers that are closer to a clarification rather than a solid analysis on a given subject.

Am i correct here or?..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

My view is that it really depends if a more in-depth answer would benefit someone asking the question.  In some cases, like saying the answer is that they want a vocoder, it is probably worth putting an answer that not only says they need a vocoder, but also explains a bit about what it is and how one is used to accomplish their goal.

On the other hand, if it is simply something like "How do I connect x to y?" One line answers like "X is XLR, Y is quarter inch and this cable will connect them." is probably ok as additional details won't really be helpful here relative to what the person actually needs to know.  It's really kind of a case by case thing.

Put another way, it isn't that one line answers are bad, it's that answers that don't give enough detail to really answer what the OP should know about the answer to their question are bad.  There are plenty of questions where one line may be enough and all they should be worrying about right now.  There are many others where that isn't really true.

That said, I would say it is generally preferable to have a short answer than an answer in comments.  An answer in comments can't be marked as a solution by the OP if it answered what they needed.  It also isn't possible for people to vote it down if they believe it to be incorrect.  Given the choice between a short answer in comments and a short answer in an answer, the later is almost always preferable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Another thing is that on the first sight the answer does not even reflect the question. It's more about decrypting a badly put question, for example a guy asks "How can I use one sound to filter another sound?" and the answer is "get a vocoder". Same thing applies to the other answer too , even if i decide to give the small answer , what is the benefit of someone who is searching for a vocoder OR someone who's looking for a way to actually "use one sound to filter another sound" , to click on that. Shouldn't that be moderated(edited)? or even deleted?

Comment: @frcake - potentially, personally it's outside of my realm of experience, so I can't tell.  That's part of why moderators don't make judgement calls on correct/incorrect answers.  It's the job of the community to deal with when it isn't really a right answer.